# nobody can get cocoadocs page for swift framework

Tags: cocoapods, jazzy

Trying to post to **CocoaPods, but when the project goes through it doesn’t generate docs** (site + docs button, instead of expand). Alternatively, when I specify a docs url the docs button doesn’t work either. According to the guides, it seems like jazzy isn’t parsing, but when I run:

```
jazzy
```

or...

```
jazzy —podspec MagicCloud.podspec
```

…it throws no errors and generates 100% documentation (which is hosted [here](https://github.com/jalingo/MagicCloud)). At the 404 page, If I select the `Alternatively, click…` or `Potential error info` buttons no luck. I’ve tried with and without a .yaml file generated [here](http://cocoadocs.org/readme/). When I try to use the following…

http://api.cocoadocs.org:4567/redeploy/MagicCloud/2.9.x     // x = 5,6,7,8,etc…
http://api.cocoadocs.org:4567/error/MagicCloud/2.9.x    // x = 5,6,7,8,etc…

…safari can’t find the server. I’ve posted so many versions at this point, any help would be much appreciated. The project is [here](https://github.com/jalingo/MagicCloud), along with it's podspec file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after contacting Orta (the developer) directly, I eventually found out that he had handed the project off to Buddy Build. With their acquisition by Apple, they're holding off on new clients and are no longer offering support to Cocoapods.

As far as I can tell, no new Cocoapods have been able to compile their docs (at least through jazzy / swift), since the announcement January 2018. If anyone knows different, or if things change, please post here. Thanks.